# windows7 get stuck on starting installation window

Tags: windows-7

i installed a new graphic card nvedia series6 2gb ddr3, and my windows get stuck on recovery when i try to do it  and it gives error when i hit start windows normally...  i tried to install fresh copy of windows but it get stuck on the first screen where to choose language and hit next, i disconnected the hard and installed new one where windows xp is already installed  and it start as usual , also i have installed a fresh copy on the hard drive of the 1st computer on other pc and did the installation but when i put it back to the 1st pc  it gives error after the windows 7 logo screen. please help.

thank you.